# Weblogic AdminServer Stuck at startup

Tags: oracle, server, weblogic, application-server

I have a weblogic server running on AWS. I took a AMI backup of it and created a new instance from the AMI.

In the new instance, when I try to start the weblogic, It stuck at following state.

```
<Dec 11, 2018 12:00:01 AM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 > 
<Dec 11, 2018 12:00:02 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> 
<Server state changed to STARTING> 
<Dec 11, 2018 12:00:02 AM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<Dec 11, 2018 12:00:02 AM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ClassicDomain/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.
```

Also see thread dump of the JVM at https://pastebin.com/D9MYSvBj

Any help would highly appreciated.

-- Arun

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed.

From the thread dump, I found following

```
 "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fda6aad4800 nid=0x6a3b runnable [0x00007fda41d5d000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(SeedGenerator.java:493)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:117)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:167)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:184)
- locked <0x00000000ece53ac0> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)
at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:433)
- locked <0x00000000ece53d60> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
at oracle.ldap.util.guid.GUIDParamGenerator.generateClockSequence(GUIDParamGenerator.java:128)
```

Did some search in Google and found a solution to change following line in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security

From

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

To

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

And restarted weblogic fixed the issue.

Ref : http://ruleoftech.com/2016/avoiding-jvm-delays-caused-by-random-number-generation

Thanks
Arun